# How To Add An Image In Blender?

Tags: blender-2.67

I want to add an image in Blender, but I don't want it to be a background image. I have a camera zooming out (going backwards) and I have some text, and I want an image over that text. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a plane above your text , then add a material to your plane  and finally add image or movie texture to the plane , this should bring you to your required result.